# Элемент массива в условии

Tags: php

С переходом на новую ОС (CentOS) и веб-сервер (nginx) перестали работать выражения следующего типа:

```
if($array['item'])
```

Т.е. теперь в случае такой проверки просто выводится ошибка:

```
Undefined index: item
```

Работает так:

```
if(isset($array['item']))
```

Полагаю, что дело в настройках php. Помогите найти ту настройку, которая отвечает за это? Копирование php.ini с рабочей конфигурации не помогает.

```
php-fpm -v
PHP 5.3.3 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Nov 22 2013 11:01:34)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
```

На той системе, в которой это работало, была установлена связка из OpenSUSE + Apache + php

Comment: А что смущает? Элемента `$array['index']` не существует, стало быть проверять его значение, тем более полагаться на него, не стоит. Очень полезное предупреждение. Но если так раздражает, то можно выключить `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: что выдаёт var_dump($array['item']) ? Или приведите полный листинг кода(с инициализацией массива и присвоения значения $array['item'])

Comment: Да нет, дело в том, что проект реально большой (~900Мб одних исходников на php), и когда это разрабатывалось (~2009 г.) таких способов проверок, видимо, не знали. К примеру, есть глобальный массив $CUR_USER, который может быть инициализирован или не инициализирован, в зависимости от того, что хранится в сессии и в файле инициализации идут проверки вида

    if($CUR_USER['settings']['lang'])

Глобально это исправить - займет очень много времени. Т.е. вариант привести все к одному виду неприемлем.

Comment: > 900 мб

![](http://scdn.memecdn.com/images/avatars/s_535386_52e11dcc1a7e1.jpg)

Comment: Ну да, серьезный коммерческий проект, разрабатывался несколько человеко-месяцев + сопровождается, как понимаете, до сих пор =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

дело не в ОС или веб-сервере. Дело в настройках PHP.

Варианты решения:

1. Рекомендуемый. Использовать isset и следить за инициализацией.
2. Запретить E_NOTICE командой error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); в начале выполнения программы
3. Изменить настройки в php.ini тот же error_reporting
4. Использовать оператор @ . `if(@$array['item'])`

Comment: Проблема оказалась совсем в другом.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
Определена кастомная функция error_handler, в которой:

    function handle_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile = null, $errline = null, $errcontext = null)
    {    
        die($errstr);
        // на нотисы и функции с @ не обращаем внимания
        if ($errno==E_NOTICE ||
     E_USER_NOTICE==$errno ||
     error_reporting()==0 ||
     (defined('E_STRICT') && (E_STRICT == $errno)) ||
     (defined('E_DEPRECATED') && (E_DEPRECATED == $errno)))
        {
     return 0;
        }
        // Код хендлер